# How can I make Ubuntu mouse sensitivity exactly the same as in Windows?

Tags: mouse, settings

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu. I'm a heavy gamer of Counter Strike and mouse sensitivity is very important. Is there any way of perfectly replicating Windows mouse sensitivity settings?

I have gone through many forums and I've only seen that useless tips are posted. I want to say that Windows mouse setting of sensitivity is completely different from Ubuntu.

I need exactly the same sensitivity because though I play in my personal PC  in Ubuntu, I go LAN parties where a Windows OS is installed. This causes some confusion between the sensitivity used at home and at LAN parties, i.e the setting area is completely different and its almost impossible to find the perfect setting.

If this problem is not solved, I would have no choice but to switch back to Windows.

Comment: Have you checked this https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/mouse-sensitivity.html

Comment: set the same settings as in windows

Comment: I recommend you switch to m_rawinput 1 as it doesn't use the OS's sensitivity as an intermediary.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set it according to your needs in 
*System Settings* → *Mouse and Touchpad*,  as shown in the image. Try to set the *Acceleration* properly .

[image]

Comment: That doesn't help at all. I agree with the OP that sensitivity in Linux is entirely different from that in Windows, making it difficult for gamers to adapt. I myself have found out, that sensitivity actually differs from DE to DE. I mainly use Xfce and the same settings don't apply in Gnome e.g. Just try it, go to Xfce and set your sensitivity and acceleration to 8, do the same under Gnome via dconf, then open up mouse settings via GUI and you will see, that your mouse sensitivity changes again.